# Adding Logstash field from grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, elk

I am trying to add a new field from grok plugin,
To get the Grok Pattern I used the Kibana debugger:
[image]
After I verified I have the correct pattern I tried to apply it in the Logstash configuration as follow:

```
# Sample Logstash configuration for creating a simple
# Beats -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch pipeline.

input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

filter {
  if "taskID" in [message] {
   grok{
      match => { "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:Application_timestamp} \[%{DATA:class}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}.*\"taskID\":\s*%{WORD:taskid}.*\"flowID\":\s*%{WORD:flowid}" }
      add_field => { "shahar_field" => "%{taskid}" }
   }
   mutate {
      add_field => { "shahar_field_mut" => "shahar_value_mut" }
   }
 }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

But Logstash fails to start with the bellow error:

```
] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 20, column 138 (byte 561) after filter {\n  if \"taskID\" in [message] {\n   grok{\n      match => { \"message\" => \"%{DATESTAMP:Application_timestamp} \\[%{DATA:class}\\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}.*\\\"taskID\\\":\\s*%{WORD:taskid}.*\"", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:42:in `compile_ast'"
```

Sample data message:

```
2021-12-29 09:36:05 [main] INFO  c.c.s.c.c.FileRecordsNormalizer - Going to send msg: {"sendingComponentType":"NORMALIZE","sendingComponentID":"1975","sentTime":"Dec 29, 2021 9:36:05 AM","messageType":"DONE","replyTo":"ETL_FLOW","originFiles":["/tmp/data_0_0_0.csv"],"taskID":7777,"taskName":"TaskName","flowID":444,"message":{"type":"com.crossix.safemine.cloud.utils.msg.response.NormalizeResponse","data":{"invalidRecordsCount":0,"errors":[null],"outputFiles":["/mnt/nfs/var/nfsshare/normalizer/7777/normalized/part-00000-9dc624ac-8dbe-42b2-a2d4-119be2c57906-c000.csv"],"status":"DONE","type":"NORMALIZE_RESPONSE"}}}
```

Comment: The error you shared is a configuration error, something in your configuration is not right, look at the line and column specified in the error, what do you have at line 20 column 138? Sharing the full pipeline would help. Looking at your grok, you have some unescaped double quotes, you need to fix that, also, the add_field needs to use [curly brackets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-add_field), not square ones.

Comment: Thanks, @leandrojmp for your comments, I've updated the question with the fixes you suggested. Now I have no errors but I can't seem to see the new field I've added in kibana.
I do see fields added by mutate but not by grok

Comment: Is your grok working? Do you have a `_grokparsefailure` in your document? Your sample data message has a json part, grok is not the best filter to parse it. If all your messages have that same format it would be better to parse it using a combination of dissect and json. Are all your messages in this same format?

Comment: I do have _grokparsefailure in the tags.
tags:beats_input_codec_plain_applied, _grokparsef
But the grok was working in the kibana debugger